# To be is to be an element?

Tags: lo.logic, mathematical-philosophy

The distinction between sets and proper classes has interesting ontological consequences.

One way to define a proper class, in the context of set theory, is to state that it is not an *element*, in a set. As a consequence, if *c* is a proper class, $\neg\exists x(x=\{c\})$. If we take an object to exist just if it is an element, it follows that proper classes do not exist.

Nevertheless, we may quantify over classes. If e.g. *R* is Russell's class $\{x|x\notin x\}$, we have that $\exists x(x=R)$; but $\neg\exists x(x=\{R\})$. One may say that Russell's class *subsists*, but does not *exist*.

Do "empty names" behave similarly, so that e.g. Sherlock Holmes *subsists*, but does not *exist*?

Does the element-strategy have noteworthy advantages? Has it been explored in the literature?

Comment: What you describe sounds formally just like a two-sorted set/class theory (e.g. Gödel–Bernays and similar) but with different terminology, saying “$a$ exists” for what would conventionally be read as “$a$ is a set”.  Is this what you have in mind, or if not, what difference besides terminological are you thinking of?  Systems with terms denoting not-necessarily-existing things have certainly been defined (e.g. Fourman/Scott’s partial logic), but in all such systems I know, “$a$ exists” is equivalent to “$\exists x\ (x=a)$”, i.e. what you’re calling “$x$ subsists”.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine It indeed has such a provenance. The terminology I opted for has bearings upon how we think about some important problems.
Yes, there are many free logics, with non-denoting terms. The approach I suggest has advantages, it seems. To wit: (1) The mere subsistence, and thus also non-existence, of proper classes, combines well with the  idea that classes merely abbreviate formulas. (2) It provides a nice semantics for fictional characters, by including them in the domain of discourse, while making statements as *SH is F* and *SH is not-F* false (if we have choice-negation).